# SQL Date value that means "PRESENT" (as of today's date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that handles Employment Date Hired and Date Left (the company)

```
EID    |Name     |Status1    |Hired          |LefttheCOmpany
11     |Kid      |Hired      |2014-01-01     |2014-01-01
12     |Suzi     |Hired      |2014-03-01     |2014-03-01
13     |Mac      |Fired      |2014-04-01     |2014-07-17
```

Both Kid and Suzi are still a part of the company, hence that's why their left Dates are equal with the same date. And what I simply do in the GUI is that I just use an IF and output PRESENT on the "LefttheCOmpany" column in the table:

```
EID    |Name     |Status1    |Hired          |LefttheCOmpany
11     |Kid      |Hired      |2014-01-01     |PRESENT
12     |Suzi     |Hired      |2014-03-01     |PRESENT
13     |Mac      |Fired      |2014-04-01     |2014-07-17
```

However, is there an *innate value* for the DATE datatype in SQL that means "PRESENT"? (Like when *NULL* means that SQL doesn't know what the value means/is.)

So that when the records are queried, SQL itself will say PRESENT (or something else) on the record?

What I did works, but maybe there's a better way of handling this.

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't set a dummy date to `LefttheCOmpany` _every single day_ for members who are still present. Better to set the date to `NULL` if they haven't left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `getdate()` function which is used to get the present date but other than that I dont think anything is there in SQL Server which will represent PRESENT

My suggestion is to keep those rows set as null and when you are querying the table then you can set the `getdate()` in that column. Something like this:

```
select getdate() as LefttheCOmpany from table where LefttheCOmpany is null
```

Making Navneet's query more useful as per my suggestion

```
select EID,Name,Status1,Hired,
case when Hired=LefttheCOmpany then 'Present' 
else LefttheCOmpany end as LefttheCOmpany 
from table
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was kind of hoping that when I just use (SELECT * ), date values would automatically output present or the present date.. No cigar huh?

Comment: Okay then, null it is

Comment: What is this supposed to do?: `Hired=isnull(LefttheCOmpany,null)`

Comment: @ypercube:- Yes I got the point. It should be getdate(). Updated my answer. Hope that makes sense now :)

Comment: Actually no. I thought you wanted to write `case when Hired = LefttheCOmpany then 'Present' else LefttheCOmpany end`. I think the OP has no Nulls in that column so the `ISNULL()` is redundant. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @ypercube:- Actually I think you confused me, I suggested OP to keep null in LefttheCOmpany column. So that was the reason for that answer. Now even I am confused!

Comment: Well, `isnull(LefttheCOmpany,null)` seems useless, nulls or no nulls in there. That's why I asked in the first place. Hadn't read carefully your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the `ISNULL()` function, if the value is null it will replace it with 'Present'.

```
SELECT ISNULL(LeftTheCompany,'Present')
```

Comment: I agree here. Remove all of the incorrect LeftTheCompany dates and reset them back to NULL. Then simply use the statement above.

Answer (score 2):

Below query will Work in `SQL`

```
select EID,Name,Status1,Hired,case when Hired = LefttheCOmpany  
then 'Present' else LefttheCOmpany end as LefttheCOmpany from table
```

Comment: The problem now is, If you have 35+ or more columns in the table and you have to output all of them.

Comment: @Malky.Kid:- Thats why we are suggesting you to keep `null` in that column

Answer (score 1):

I also believe NULL is an appropriate entry under the column LefttheCOmpany, you may be surprised how sensitive folk get with data like that.

But putting that aside why would you not use COALESCE() or ISNULL()?

```
select COALESCE(LefttheCOmpany, getdate()) as LefttheCOmpany from ThatTable

select ISNULL(LefttheCOmpany, getdate()) as LefttheCOmpany from ThatTable
```

For a long explanation of COALESCE vs. ISNULL
see: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

---

EDIT

It should be stated that a date(or datetime) column cannot also carry strings, so if you literally want to see "Present" in that column you will have to convert the field to |n|var|char  e.g.

```
COALESCE( convert(varchar(10),LefttheCOmpany,120) , 'Present')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with NULL is you can't compare it.  When a NULL is encountered, you have to assign a value that means something to you, like 0, or -1, or whatever.  In this case the column does not apply to currently employed.  I would convey that an employee has not left the company by assigning a future date, aka, the max value (9999-12-31).

Comment: You can compare NULL using  "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL". NULL also means no value and when the person is still with the company the correct use of the field is to confer that there is no value for this employee.

Comment: select 'test'
where 1 > NULL  *I should have been more explicit.*  I meant assign it a values using ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value ).  It is the replacement_value that will get you in trouble, 10 years later, when a new programmer is looking at your table values.